# Remove repetitve Consecutive words from string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove repetitive words from the string (only consecutive).

```
$str = 'abc,def,fgh,fgh,xna,fgh,xyz,xyz,xyz,tr,tr,xna';
```

My desired output string is:

```
abc,def,fgh,xna,fgh,xyz,tr,xna
```

I can get the result I want in php using this:

```
$ip = explode(',', $str);
$op = [];$last = null;
for($i=0;$i<count($ip);$i++){
    if ($last == $ip[$i]) {
        continue;
    }
    $op[]=$last=$ip[$i];
}
$ip = implode(',', $op);
```

But was looking for the regex approach. So far I have got closer with these two regexes:

```
$after = preg_replace('/(?:^|,)([^,]+)(?=.*,\1(?:,|$))/m', '', $str);
output : abc,def,fgh,xyz,tr,xna

$after = preg_replace('/([^,]+)(,[ ]*\1)+/m', '', $str);
output : abc,degh,fgh,xna,fgh,,,xna
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
preg_replace('~(?<![^,])([^,]+)(?:,\1)+(?![^,])~', '$1', $str)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yv1htV/1)

If there is a need to support any 0 or more whitespace chars between the commas and repetitive values, [add `\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/Yv1htV/2) (*0 or more whitespaces*) pattern before `\1`.

**Details**

- `(?<![^,])` - start of string or any char but a comma
- `([^,]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than a comma
- `(?:,\1)+` - one or more sequences of a comma and the value in Group 1
- `(?![^,])` - end of string or a char other than a comma.

Comment: @Progrock This expression is not automatically generated, the point is 1) you need a starting boundary, 2) the repetitive pattern inside a capturing group, 3) a group with a delimiter and a backreference to Group 1 that should be repeated 1 or more times, and then 4) a trailing boundary. Without the boundaries, part of a value captured in Group 1 [may get matched erroneously](https://regex101.com/r/XnKu6H/1).

Answer (score 2):

```php
$after = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,)([^,]+)(,\s*\1)+/', '$1', $str);
```

P.S. You can get rid of `\s*` from the regexp above if there is no whitespace expecter after `,`. I just looked at your `[ ]*` and figured you may have whitespace.

Comment: (apologies for getting and posting eroneous output from your solution as I failed to copy this regex correctly earlier.)

Answer (score 1):

Iterating with strtok, only glue pieces that are not like the last:

```
<?php

$str = 'abc,def,fgh,fgh,xna,fgh,xyz,xyz,xyz,tr,tr,xna';

$out = $last = strtok($str, ',');
while($current = strtok(','))
    if($current !== $last)
        $out .= ',' . ($last = $current);

echo $out;
```

Output:

```
abc,def,fgh,xna,fgh,xyz,tr,xna
```

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it this way:

```php
$after = preg_replace('/(?<=,|^)([^,]+)\K(,\1)+(?=,|$)/', '', $str);
```

This will output `abc,def,fgh,xna,fgh,xyz,tr,xna`.

What it does:

- `(?<=,|^)` looks if the is a comma or the string start right before
- `([^,]+)` matches anything except commas (search pattern)
- `\K` resets the internal cursor and "forgets" the stuff before (e.g. it doen't count as matched longer)
- `(,\1)+` matches multiple appearances of the first defined search pattern
- `(?=,|$)` looks if the next char will be a comma again or if the string ends

So the idea is, to select repeatings of any pattern (only the repeatings) and replacing them with nothing.

**Update:**

Fixed the pattern by adding `(?=,|$)`. Otherwise this test input would fail
 and kill the `xna` part completely.

```php
$str = 'bc,abc,abc,abc,def,fgh,fgh,xna,fgh,xyz,xyz,xyz,tr,tr,xna,xna,xnabc';
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/Yv1htV/3

Answer (score 1):

With `array_reduce`:

```
$arr = explode(',', $str);
$prev = array_shift($arr);
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $i) use (&$prev) {
    if ($prev==$i) return $c;
    $prev=$i;
    return "$c,$i";
}, $prev);
```