# regex for repeating word to repeating two words

Tags: javascript, python, r, regex

I am trying to write some regex pattern that will look through a sentence and remove any one or two sequentially repeated words

for example:

```
# R code below
string_a = "hello hello, how are you you?"
string_b = "goodbye world goodbye world, I am flying to the the moon!"

gsub(pattern, "", string_a)
gsub(pattern, "", string_b)
```

Desired outputs are

```
[1] "hello, how are you?"
[2] "goodbye world, I am flying to the moon!"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57136806/remove-repetitve-consecutive-words-from-string possibly try this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 gsub("(\\S+(\\s+\\S+)?)\\s+\\1+", "\\1", c(string_a, string_b))
```

-output

```
[1] "hello, how are you?"                  
[2] "goodbye world, I am flying to the moon!"
```